# ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount -1, 10) PROBLEM

Tags: listbox

I'd appreciate your help with the following concern.

I'm trying to complete a ListBox content; however I'm struggling with a simple detail that I don't know how to deal with.

I noticed that the second part of the list content doesn't accept two digits. Here is the **code below**. (The problem runs from the "ListCount - 1, 10" and so on)

last_row = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

```
For row_l = 3 To last_row

If UCase(Cells(row_l, 4).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TBsearch_bid.Value) & "*" Or UCase(Cells(row_l, 3).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TBsearch_bid.Value) & "*" Or UCase(Cells(row_l, 5).Value) Like "*" & UCase(Me.TBsearch_bid.Value) & "*" Then

Me.ListBox1.AddItem Cells(row_l, 1)

Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 0) = Cells(row_l, 1)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(row_l, 2)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(row_l, 3)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(row_l, 4)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cells(row_l, 5)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cells(row_l, 6)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = Cells(row_l, 7)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = Cells(row_l, 8)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 8) = Cells(row_l, 9)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 9) = Cells(row_l, 10)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 10) = Cells(row_l, 11) <-
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 11) = Cells(row_l, 12)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 12) = Cells(row_l, 13)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 13) = Cells(row_l, 14)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 14) = Cells(row_l, 15)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 15) = Cells(row_l, 16)
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 16) = Cells(row_l, 17)
    
End If

Next row_l
```

## Thanks in advance guys!

I tried to write the 10, 11, 12, etc. with different formats to get it right, but it didn't work.
Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, "10") for example.